# Java IF-ELSE IF-ELSE skipping the if and else if check and prints out else statement automatically

Tags: java

Java 11.6 In this BMI calculator that will take in Person's weight, height and calculate the BMI. The BMI is calculated properly however in the classify BMI method the program skips the **if and else if** check and just prints out the else statement which is "obese" for every test. Is the loop implemented incorrectly? or the value of BMI is not initiating in the loop. When I print out the BMI, I do see that for every test the BMI does change so that is not a problem.

**The PersonWeight.java class**

```
import java.time.Year;


public class PersonWeight {


    private double height;
    private double weight;

    public PersonWeight() {

        height = 0;
        weight = 0;

    }

    public PersonWeight(double h, double w) {

        height = h;
        weight = w;

    }



    public void setHeight(double h) {
        this.height = h;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setWeight(double w) {
        this.weight = w;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }



    public double ComputeBMI() {

        double bmi = ((weight)/(height*height));
        return bmi;
    }



}
```

**The test class that has the main method**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestPersonWeight {



    public static void classifyBMI() {
        PersonWeight PersonWeight = new PersonWeight();
        double bmi = PersonWeight.ComputeBMI();


        if(bmi<18.5) {
            System.out.printf("Underweight");

        }else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi<25) {
            System.out.printf("Normal Weight");
        }else if (bmi >=25 && bmi<30) {
            System.out.printf("Overweight");
        }else  {
            System.out.printf("Obese");

        }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        TestPersonWeight TestPersonWeight = new TestPersonWeight();
        PersonWeight PersonWeight = new PersonWeight()
        System.out.printf("Enter person's Height in Meters: ");
        double h = input.nextDouble();
        PersonWeight.setHeight(h);


        System.out.printf("Enter person's Weight in Kilograms: ");
        double w = input.nextDouble();
        PersonWeight.setWeight(w);

        PersonWeight.ComputeBMI();
        System.out.printf("%n Height: " + PersonWeight.getHeight());
        System.out.printf("%n Weight: " + PersonWeight.getWeight());
        System.out.printf("%n BMI: " + PersonWeight.ComputeBMI());
        classifyBMI();

    }
}
```

Comment: first trick: print the value of `bmi` **just** before the `if` (or, better, use a debugger to see its value) - and maybe, after that, check the values of `PersonWeight`

Comment: @Henry double division does not throw an exception in that case, just will result in `NaN` (valid value for `double`)

Comment: @user85421 when i print out the bmi right before the if statement it shows "NanObese"

Comment: `NaN` means Not A Number, mostly because there is a (double) division like `0.0 / 0.0`

Comment: @user85421 indeed, presumably it never happened to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `classifyBMI()` method creates a new `PersonWeight` where the height and weight remain `0.0`, so you are dividing `0.0` by `0.0`, which results in `NaN`. Hence, none of the comparisons evaluates to `true`, and you end up with the else clause being executed.

You should change that method to be an instance method (i.e. not `static`), and call it for the `PersonWeight` instance that you create in your `main` method.

Or, as an alternative, keep that method `static`, but pass to it the previously calculated `bmi` value.

i.e. in your `main` write:

```
double bmi = PersonWeight.ComputeBMI();
System.out.printf("%n Height: " + PersonWeight.getHeight());
System.out.printf("%n Weight: " + PersonWeight.getWeight());
System.out.printf("%n BMI: " + bmi);
classifyBMI(bmi);
```

and `classifyBMI` will become:

```
public static void classifyBMI (double bmi) {
    if(bmi < 18.5) {
        System.out.printf("Underweight");
    } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
        System.out.printf("Normal Weight");
    } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30) {
        System.out.printf("Overweight");
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Obese");
    }
}
```

P.S. using the same identifier - `PersonWeight` - for both your class name and the variable name is a bad practice. Use `personWeight` for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
PersonWeight personWeight = new PersonWeight();
double bmi = personWeight.computeBMI();
```

This always returns NaN (Not a number) because you compute on a fresh new object which has only zeroes in it. Division by zero is not allowed, hence the result is NaN. All if-comparisons fail because NaN cannot be compared to any number.

Solution 1: Move the ``classifyBMI()`method inside the`PersonWeight``` class and use the current class instance attributes (now a new class with zeroes) for the calculation.

Solution 2: Pass the filled ```` PersonWeight``` instance to the ````classifyBMI()``` method as an argument and use that for the calculation.

Solution 3: Pass the `bmi` value to the ``classifyBMI()``` method as an argument and use that for the calculation.

The following code demonstrates all three solutions:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

    public static class PersonWeight
    {
        private double height;
        private double weight;

        public PersonWeight()
        {
            height = 0;
            weight = 0;
        }

        public void setHeight(double h)
        {
            this.height = h;
        }

        public double getHeight()
        {
            return height;
        }

        public void setWeight(double w)
        {
            this.weight = w;
        }

        public double getWeight()
        {
            return weight;
        }

        public double computeBMI()
        {
            double bmi = ((weight) / (height * height));
            return bmi;
        }

        private void classifyBMI1()
        {
            double bmi = ((weight) / (height * height));

            if (bmi < 18.5)
            {
                System.out.println("Underweight");
            }
            else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25)
            {
                System.out.println("Normal Weight");
            }
            else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30)
            {
                System.out.println("Overweight");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Obese");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void classifyBMI2(PersonWeight personWeight)
    {
        double bmi = personWeight.computeBMI();
        if (bmi < 18.5)
        {
            System.out.println("Underweight");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25)
        {
            System.out.println("Normal Weight");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30)
        {
            System.out.println("Overweight");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Obese");
        }
    }

    private static void classifyBMI3(double bmi)
    {
        if (bmi < 18.5)
        {
            System.out.println("Underweight");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25)
        {
            System.out.println("Normal Weight");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30)
        {
            System.out.println("Overweight");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Obese");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        PersonWeight personWeight = new PersonWeight();

        System.out.printf("Enter person's Height in Meters: ");
        double h = input.nextDouble();
        personWeight.setHeight(h);

        System.out.printf("Enter person's Weight in Kilograms: ");
        double w = input.nextDouble();
        personWeight.setWeight(w);

        System.out.printf("%nHeight: %f%n", personWeight.getHeight());
        System.out.printf("Weight: %f%n", personWeight.getWeight());
        System.out.printf("BMI: %f2%n", personWeight.computeBMI());

        personWeight.classifyBMI1();
        classifyBMI2(personWeight);
        classifyBMI3(personWeight.computeBMI());
    }
}
```

I also fixed other things:

Variable names and method names should start with a small letter. Upper case beginnings are reserved for class name. To print simple strings use `println()` instead of `printf()` for better performance. When you use `printf()` to output variables, then use placeholders like `%f`instead of string concatenation. Again this provides better performance.

Comment: I spent much time trying to write a real good answer, so someone else was faster and got the points.